# How can I use useOneOfInterfaces flag in openapi-generator?

Tags: swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I wanted to fix a bug with openapi generator and I figured what I actually need is to set `useOneOfInterfaces = True` in [openapi-generator/..../codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L231](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L231)

Currently I forked `OpenAPITools/openapi-generator` [repo](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) and manually edited that flag and rebuild `openapi-generator` that I'm using. Is there a way to pass this flag as a command line argument instead such that I'll be able to use the latest binary from `OpenAPITools/openapi-generator`? I.e.,

```
openapi-generator generate -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml -g ruby -o /tmp/test/ --enableUseOneOfInterfaces
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flag is currently only set in a single code generator, the Swift5ClientCodengen. There is no general parsing of this flag. If you'd like for this flag to be generally available feel free to submit an issue in the repository or even better add a pull request that adds parsing this flag to the DefaultCodegen.